# how to get the sum of duplicate values in a list in dart?

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, flutter, dart

I want to get the sum of the duplicate values and put them on another list.. is it possible?

```
List list = [1, 1 , 2, 3,2];
List newList = [2,4,3];
```

Comment: sure use [groupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html) top level function from `collection` library

Comment: `print(groupBy([1,1,2,3,2], (e) => e).values.map((e) => e.reduce((sum, e) => sum + e)));`

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is possible. You can define a temporary list to prevent duplicate items in the list. Try this:

```
List list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 2];
List tempList = [];
List newList = [2, 4, 3];

for (var item in list) {
  if (!tempList.contains(item)) {
    newList.add(list.where((e) => e == item).length * item);
    tempList.add(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is where [groupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html) is used for: `print(groupBy([1,1,2,3,2], (e) => e).values.map((e) => e.reduce((sum, e) => sum + e))); `

Comment: or your (faster) way: `print(groupBy([1,1,2,3,2], (e) => e).values.map((e) => e[0] * e.length));`

Comment: You are great :)